# Unable to export a report from msaccess to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, microsoft-access

I need to export a report generated using microsft access to a sharepoint site. I am done with the report. Now when exporting the report to sharepoint list(option was there in access).am unable to export it as Export->Sharepoint List option is disabled. anu suggestion on how to export report to a sharepoint site. Export can either be to a list or a library in sharepoint.